# Silverlight 3 - TreeView: Scroll to a particular item

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0, treeview

In Silverlight 3 I have a TreeView bound to an ObservableCollection in my ViewModel.  The items are formated with a Hierarchical Data Template.  When the collection is populated from a WebService and the TreeView displays that collection, it scrolls to the bottom of the list.

How would I go about finding a particular item that might be anywhere in the Hierarchy?  And more importantly, how would I scroll that item either to the middle or top of the TreeView control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this with the Toolkit Treeview you would have to write an attached behaviour - sorry not familiar enough with these to help on that.

However, you can do this out-of-the-box with the Telerik treeview control which has a feature called **Bring into View**.

Details on this feature can be found at http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radtreeview-features-treeviewitem-bring-into-view-support.html. Downside is that this control is not free :-(